# A word for individual letters?

Tags: typography

Is there another word for individual letters of the alphabet, perhaps a typographical reference?

Comment: _A word for individual letters?_ That's a tough one, but I'd like to buy a word: **letter**.

Answer (score 6):

**[glyph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glyph)**

> A glyph  is an element of writing: **An individual mark** on a written medium that contributes to the meaning of what is written.

---

> In **typography**, a glyph has a slightly different definition: it is "**the specific shape, design, or representation of a character**".
>
> It is a particular graphical representation, in a particular typeface, of an element of written language, which could be a grapheme, or part of a grapheme, or sometimes several graphemes in combination (a composed glyph)

**Note:** It goes beyond letters and covers marks in alphabetic systems as well (like a diacritic mark)

Answer (score 2):

Consider **[character](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/character)**

> A printed or written letter or symbol.

Also **[sort](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/sort)**

> (often plural) (printing) any of the individual characters making up a fount of type

Answer (score 0):

Character. Take a look at the Character Map on your computer.